# How do I upload an email attachment sent as application/octet-stream to google drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I receive nightly emails which contain excel files as attachments, yet the sending company do not define the content type so that the files arrive with content type=application/octet-stream

My script is attempting to upload the files to my google drive as Google Sheets, however the upload fails as the script does not know what type of file it is.

I have tried forwarding the attachment and giving it the correct content type but the forwarded file also arrives as octet-stream.

Any ideas what I can do to get past this?

The gist of the code I am using is as follows:

```
var ureadMsgsCount = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount();
if (ureadMsgsCount > 0) {

var threads = GmailApp.search("Excel Files")
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  if (threads[i].isInInbox()) {

    messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {

      if (messages[j].isUnread()) {

        var attachments = messages[j].getAttachments();
        for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {

          // Is the attachment an excel file
          var excelFile = attachments[k];
          var fileName = attachments[k].getName();
          var contentType = attachments[k].getContentType();

          if (fileName.indexOf("xls") > -1) {
            var folderId = getFolderID('saved files');
            var resource = {
              title: fileName.replace(/.xls?/, ""),
              mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
              parents: [{ id: folderId }]
            };
            Drive.Files.insert(resource, excelFile);
          }
         }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

many thanks.

The error which is thrown is "GoogleJsonResponseException: Invalid mime type provided"

Comment: It seems that ``file`` of ``Drive.Files.insert(resource, file)`` cannot be found in your script. And if the error occurs, can you provide the error messages?

Comment: Thanks Tanaike. I copied the code from a function and forgot to rename the parameter.  Fixed now.

Comment: For known common mimetypes, why are you specifying the mimetype string? use the `MimeType` enums. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type

Comment: It makes no difference though. I defined it explicitly as I wanted to be sure the error message I was getting was not due to a Mimetype enum.

Comment: In my environment, I tested to do the same situation with you. An excel file is sent as an email with an attachment file of ``application/octet-stream``. In this time, I confirmed that the mimeType of uploaded file is ``application/octet-stream``. When the attachment file is uploaded as ``application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`` using your script, the file is converted to Spreadsheet. So can I ask you about the detail information of your situation? What is the mimeType of the original file which was attached to email?

Comment: This is what arrives in the headers.  I am not privy to what MimeType was used when the file was attached to the mail. It is sent from a bank and most people download the file manually.

Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="B015641268344.xls"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="B015641268344.xls"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Description: B015641268344.xls

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this problem I was able to solve it by using the **setContentTypeFromExtension()** method from the GmailApp class.

Just replace

```
var excelFile = attachments[k];
var fileName = attachments[k].getName();
var contentType = attachments[k].getContentType();
```

with

```
var excelFile = attachments[k].setContentTypeFromExtension();
var fileName = attachments[k].getName();
var contentType = excelFile.getContentType();
```

This could of course be written in less lines but it's handy to have the separate values when running in debug.